# Parse PHP code in a custom field

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-fields

I am using advance custom field pluggin.
I have created a custom field with type as text with following content:

```
<div id="comp_for_empty" class="dvDobbel"><div class="dvLeft"><div class="dvGarderobestang">
<img src="<?php echo  get_template_directory_uri(); ?>images/gasd.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="dvGarderobestang"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/sdg.png" alt="" /></div></div><div class="dvVerticalRod"></div>
<div class="dvRight"><div class="dvGarderobestang2"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/images/asfd.png" alt="" /></div></div></div>
```

But that php code is not getting parsed its displaying the content as it is .
Therefore I am not getting the correct path.

Please tell how to parse the php code also from custom field so that i can get the get_template_directory_uri() function work

Comment: This can be a stupid question but, are you working with a .php file or a .html ?

Comment: yea I know this can be a stupid question ... please tell if there is any other solution ,.,,i am using this in a php file

Comment: Create a simple `test.php` file with `<?php echo "Hello World";` and check, is that running.

Comment: From what you mentioning it seem like the plugin isn't supporting php inside the custom fields,to make sure just contact the plugin developer.

Comment: That's how it supposed to be - enabling PHP in a text field would be a major security issue. Put the template path instead.

Comment: @QBernard :I am using .php file . This is not stupidity , its the requirement of my project.I am using woocommerce. I want every product to store a html php  content , because of that i am using custom field.If you have any other solution than please tell me.

Comment: @lolka_bolka : everythng else is working fyn